# MacOS PostScript Typ 1 fonts are 0 bytes after compressing with Python make_archiv

Tags: python-3.x, macos, zip, shutil

I have a bunch of old Mac PostScript Typ 1 fonts that I want to compress in a zip file.
After compressing the folder with the fonts in it I uncompress the zip-File and all Fonts inside show 0 bytes and are no longer usable.

They look like this, before compression:

[image: Mac PostScript Type 1 Fonts before compression]

And like this, after compression:
[image: Mac PostScript Type 1 Fonts after compression]

My Code:

```
shutil.make_archive(ordner, 'zip', ordner)
```

Compressing the font-directory with the nativ MacOS archive program does not damage the fonts.

**Update:** I tried to compress my files with the original Unix-Tool over the command line (Terminal). With this code:

```
zip -r -X compressed_directory.zip directory_to_be_compressed/
```

I get the same broken result.
So I think I run into a problem that lies on a deeper level of Mac OS.

**Update:** As suggested by benwiggy I tried the following, without the -X flag. Same result:

```
 zip -r compressed_directory.zip directory_to_be_compressed/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research on old MacOS Resource Forks and a lot of testing, I found no way to include the resource fork of old MacOS Post Script Type 1 fonts in to a .zip File without using the native "Archiv Utility" or some other third party tools like Keka. The Python `shutil.make_archiv()` command does not include the resource fork for this type of file, neither does it the Unix Command Line tool `zip`.
I found some usefull information on this topic on Xhalees's blog (very nicely and comprehensively explained): http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/macosx.html

The solution I came up with is to call the MacOS Terminal `ditto` command inside Python with the `os module` and let do it the work.

```
import os
os.system("ditto -ck --rsrc --keepParent directory_to_zip zipped_file.zip")
```

Answer (score 1):

Old Type 1 PostScript fonts use the MacOS Resource fork to store their data. This part of the filesystem isn't always handled well by Unix tools, unless they are explicitly written to cope with Mac resource forks.

The bundled zip utility in the MacOs CLI should include resource forks by default (since 10.3). It's possible the python util doesn't access the Mac-friendly utility.

Your zip command uses the -X flag, which deliberately excludes extended file attributes and other things, which probably includes resource forks.

Comment: Thank you, you're answer let me think and do some google work and came up with this excellent article: https://blog.jay2k1.com/2010/02/03/why-macs-may-have-trouble-with-fonts-from-smb-shares/ I think I have some issues with the resource fork that will not be included in the zip file with the unix or python tool. I have to do more search and will tell you if I found a solution.